# CMake error building Openmvg in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, cmake, photogrammetry

I'm trying to set up a free photogrammety workflow on Ubuntu 16.04. When trying to install Openmvg and while I'm following this steps https://github.com/openMVG/openMVG/blob/master/BUILD.md#linux I got an error when I try this command:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE ../openMVG/src/
```

fail with error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:13 (if):
  if given arguments:

    "3.5.1" "VERSION_GREATER_EQUAL" "3.17"

  Unknown arguments specified


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/root/openMVG_Build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log"
```

CMakeOutput.log:

```
The system is: Linux - 4.15.0-46-generic - x86_64
Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" succeeded.
Compiler: /usr/bin/cc
Build flags:
Id flags:

The output was:
0


Compilation of the C compiler identification source "CMakeCCompilerId.c" produced "a.out"

The C compiler identification is GNU, found in "/root/openMVG_Build/CMakeFiles/3.5.1/CompilerIdC/a.out"

Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" succeeded.
Compiler: /usr/bin/c++
Build flags:
Id flags:

The output was:
0


Compilation of the CXX compiler identification source "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" produced "a.out"

The CXX compiler identification is GNU, found in "/root/openMVG_Build/CMakeFiles/3.5.1/CompilerIdCXX/a.out"

Determining if the C compiler works passed with the following output:
Change Dir: /root/openMVG_Build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make" "cmTC_43767/fast"
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_43767.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_43767.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/root/openMVG_Build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_43767.dir/testCCompiler.c.o
/usr/bin/cc     -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_43767.dir/testCCompiler.c.o   -c /root/openMVG_Build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c
Linking C executable cmTC_43767
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_43767.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc       CMakeFiles/cmTC_43767.dir/testCCompiler.c.o  -o cmTC_43767 -rdynamic
make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/openMVG_Build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'


Detecting C compiler ABI info compiled with the following output:
Change Dir: /root/openMVG_Build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make" "cmTC_50599/fast"
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_50599.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_50599.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/root/openMVG_Build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_50599.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o
/usr/bin/cc     -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_50599.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o   -c /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/CMakeCCompilerABI.c
Linking C executable cmTC_50599
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_50599.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc      -v CMakeFiles/cmTC_50599.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o  -o cmTC_50599 -rdynamic
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/usr/bin/cc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-5/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr $
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12)
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../lib/:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'cmTC_50599' '-rdynamic' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/collect2 -plugin /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/liblto_plugin.so -plugin-opt=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/lto-wrapper -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/ccDCeBXr.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s --sysroot=/ --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 --hash-style=gnu --as-needed -export-dynamic -dyna$
make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/openMVG_Build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'


Parsed C implicit link information from above output:
  link line regex: [^( *|.*[/\])(ld|([^/\]+-)?ld|collect2)[^/\]*( |$)]
  ignore line: [Change Dir: /root/openMVG_Build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp]
  ignore line: []
  ignore line: [Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make" "cmTC_50599/fast"]
  ignore line: [/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_50599.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_50599.dir/build]
  ignore line: [make[1]: Entering directory '/root/openMVG_Build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp']
  ignore line: [Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_50599.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o]
  ignore line: [/usr/bin/cc     -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_50599.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o   -c /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/CMakeCCompilerABI.c]
  ignore line: [Linking C executable cmTC_50599]
  ignore line: [/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_50599.dir/link.txt --verbose=1]
  ignore line: [/usr/bin/cc      -v CMakeFiles/cmTC_50599.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o  -o cmTC_50599 -rdynamic  ]
  ignore line: [Using built-in specs.]
  ignore line: [COLLECT_GCC=/usr/bin/cc]
  ignore line: [COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/lto-wrapper]
  ignore line: [Target: x86_64-linux-gnu]
  ignore line: [Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-5/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-5 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --e$
  ignore line: [Thread model: posix]
  ignore line: [gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12) ]
  ignore line: [COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/]
  ignore line: [LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../lib/:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/]
  ignore line: [COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'cmTC_50599' '-rdynamic' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64']
  link line: [ /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/collect2 -plugin /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/liblto_plugin.so -plugin-opt=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/lto-wrapper -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/ccDCeBXr.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s --sysroot=/ --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 --hash-style=gnu --as-needed -export$
    arg [/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/collect2] ==> ignore
    arg [-plugin] ==> ignore
    arg [/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/liblto_plugin.so] ==> ignore
    arg [-plugin-opt=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/lto-wrapper] ==> ignore
    arg [-plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/ccDCeBXr.res] ==> ignore
    arg [-plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc] ==> ignore
    arg [-plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s] ==> ignore
    arg [-plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc] ==> ignore
    arg [-plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc] ==> ignore
    arg [-plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s] ==> ignore
    arg [--sysroot=/] ==> ignore
    arg [--build-id] ==> ignore
    arg [--eh-frame-hdr] ==> ignore
    arg [-m] ==> ignore
    arg [elf_x86_64] ==> ignore
    arg [--hash-style=gnu] ==> ignore
    arg [--as-needed] ==> ignore
    arg [-export-dynamic] ==> ignore
    arg [-dynamic-linker] ==> ignore
    arg [/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2] ==> ignore
    arg [-zrelro] ==> ignore
    arg [-o] ==> ignore
    arg [cmTC_50599] ==> ignore
    arg [/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o] ==> ignore
    arg [/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o] ==> ignore
    arg [/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/crtbegin.o] ==> ignore
    arg [-L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5] ==> dir [/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5]
    arg [-L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu] ==> dir [/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu]
    arg [-L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../lib] ==> dir [/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../lib]
    arg [-L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu] ==> dir [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu]
arg [-L/usr/lib/../lib] ==> dir [/usr/lib/../lib]
    arg [-L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../..] ==> dir [/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../..]
    arg [CMakeFiles/cmTC_50599.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o] ==> ignore
    arg [-lgcc] ==> lib [gcc]
    arg [--as-needed] ==> ignore
    arg [-lgcc_s] ==> lib [gcc_s]
    arg [--no-as-needed] ==> ignore
    arg [-lc] ==> lib [c]
    arg [-lgcc] ==> lib [gcc]
    arg [--as-needed] ==> ignore
    arg [-lgcc_s] ==> lib [gcc_s]
    arg [--no-as-needed] ==> ignore
    arg [/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/crtend.o] ==> ignore
    arg [/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o] ==> ignore
  remove lib [gcc]
  remove lib [gcc_s]
  remove lib [gcc]
  remove lib [gcc_s]
  collapse library dir [/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5] ==> [/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5]
  collapse library dir [/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu] ==> [/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu]
  collapse library dir [/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../lib] ==> [/usr/lib]
  collapse library dir [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu] ==> [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu]
  collapse library dir [/lib/../lib] ==> [/lib]
  collapse library dir [/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu] ==> [/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu]
  collapse library dir [/usr/lib/../lib] ==> [/usr/lib]
  collapse library dir [/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../..] ==> [/usr/lib]
  implicit libs: [c]
  implicit dirs: [/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu;/usr/lib;/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu;/lib]
implicit fwks: []




Detecting C [-std=c11] compiler features compiled with the following output:
Change Dir: /root/openMVG_Build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make" "cmTC_94e20/fast"
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_94e20.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_94e20.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/root/openMVG_Build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_94e20.dir/feature_tests.c.o
/usr/bin/cc    -std=c11 -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_94e20.dir/feature_tests.c.o   -c /root/openMVG_Build/CMakeFiles/feature_tests.c
Linking C executable cmTC_94e20
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_94e20.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc       CMakeFiles/cmTC_94e20.dir/feature_tests.c.o  -o cmTC_94e20 -rdynamic
make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/openMVG_Build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'


    Feature record: C_FEATURE:1c_function_prototypes
    Feature record: C_FEATURE:1c_restrict
    Feature record: C_FEATURE:1c_static_assert
    Feature record: C_FEATURE:1c_variadic_macros


Detecting C [-std=c99] compiler features compiled with the following output:
Change Dir: /root/openMVG_Build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make" "cmTC_87b15/fast"
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_87b15.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_87b15.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/root/openMVG_Build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_87b15.dir/feature_tests.c.o
/usr/bin/cc    -std=c99 -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_87b15.dir/feature_tests.c.o   -c /root/openMVG_Build/CMakeFiles/feature_tests.c
Linking C executable cmTC_87b15
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_87b15.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc       CMakeFiles/cmTC_87b15.dir/feature_tests.c.o  -o cmTC_87b15 -rdynamic
make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/openMVG_Build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'


    Feature record: C_FEATURE:1c_function_prototypes
    Feature record: C_FEATURE:1c_restrict
    Feature record: C_FEATURE:0c_static_assert
    Feature record: C_FEATURE:1c_variadic_macros


Detecting C [-std=c90] compiler features compiled with the following output:
Change Dir: /root/openMVG_Build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make" "cmTC_955ac/fast"
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_955ac.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_955ac.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/root/openMVG_Build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_955ac.dir/feature_tests.c.o
/usr/bin/cc    -std=c90 -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_955ac.dir/feature_tests.c.o   -c /root/openMVG_Build/CMakeFiles/feature_tests.c
Linking C executable cmTC_955ac
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_955ac.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc       CMakeFiles/cmTC_955ac.dir/feature_tests.c.o  -o cmTC_955ac -rdynamic
make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/openMVG_Build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'


    Feature record: C_FEATURE:1c_function_prototypes
    Feature record: C_FEATURE:0c_restrict
    Feature record: C_FEATURE:0c_static_assert
    Feature record: C_FEATURE:0c_variadic_macros
Determining if the CXX compiler works passed with the following output:
Change Dir: /root/openMVG_Build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make" "cmTC_a880c/fast"
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_a880c.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_a880c.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/root/openMVG_Build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_a880c.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o
/usr/bin/c++      -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_a880c.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -c /root/openMVG_Build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCXXCompiler.cxx
Linking CXX executable cmTC_a880c
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_a880c.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++        CMakeFiles/cmTC_a880c.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o  -o cmTC_a880c -rdynamic
make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/openMVG_Build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'


Detecting CXX compiler ABI info compiled with the following output:
Change Dir: /root/openMVG_Build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make" "cmTC_3149e/fast"
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_3149e.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_3149e.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/root/openMVG_Build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_3149e.dir/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.o
/usr/bin/c++      -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_3149e.dir/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.o -c /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp
Linking CXX executable cmTC_3149e
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_3149e.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++       -v CMakeFiles/cmTC_3149e.dir/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.o  -o cmTC_3149e -rdynamic
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/usr/bin/c++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-5/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-5 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-$
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12)
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../lib/:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'cmTC_3149e' '-rdynamic' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/collect2 -plugin /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/liblto_plugin.so -plugin-opt=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/lto-wrapper -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/ccOyezRP.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc --sysroot=/ --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 --hash-style=gnu --as-needed -export-dynamic -dyna$
make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/openMVG_Build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'


Parsed CXX implicit link information from above output:
  link line regex: [^( *|.*[/\])(ld|([^/\]+-)?ld|collect2)[^/\]*( |$)]
  ignore line: [Change Dir: /root/openMVG_Build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp]
  ignore line: []
  ignore line: [Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make" "cmTC_3149e/fast"]
  ignore line: [/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_3149e.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_3149e.dir/build]
  ignore line: [make[1]: Entering directory '/root/openMVG_Build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp']
  ignore line: [Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_3149e.dir/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.o]
  ignore line: [/usr/bin/c++      -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_3149e.dir/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.o -c /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp]
  ignore line: [Linking CXX executable cmTC_3149e]
  ignore line: [/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_3149e.dir/link.txt --verbose=1]
  ignore line: [/usr/bin/c++       -v CMakeFiles/cmTC_3149e.dir/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.o  -o cmTC_3149e -rdynamic  ]
  ignore line: [Using built-in specs.]
  ignore line: [COLLECT_GCC=/usr/bin/c++]
  ignore line: [COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/lto-wrapper]
  ignore line: [Target: x86_64-linux-gnu]
  ignore line: [Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-5/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-5 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --e$
  ignore line: [Thread model: posix]
```

........
etc etc etc

Any solution to this? Alternative way to install it?

Thanks again,

F.

Comment: It seems you CMake is too old for understand `VERSION_GREATER_EQUAL` comparision, which is firstly [appeared](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/if.html) in CMake 3.7.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried many ways to upgrade but I still can't get it. Now it seems like it is not installed, but I did installed it many times in fact.